# Google Play services integration fails with Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, google-play-services

I'm using latest Google Play services v4323030, downloaded BaseUtility library from GIT as written in google developer documentation.

In project using only GameHelper and GameHelperUtils classes without BaseGameActivity.

Initializing GameHelper in OnCreate method:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            if (!isGameCenterDisabled())
            { 
                gameHelper = new GameHelper(Cocos2dxActivity.this,GameHelper.CLIENT_ALL);
                 GameHelperListener listener = new GameHelper.GameHelperListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSignInSucceeded() {
                            // handle sign-in succeess
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSignInFailed() {
                            // handle sign-in failure (e.g. show Sign In button)
                        }

                    };
                
                
                
                gameHelper.setup(listener);
                gameHelper.onStart(Cocos2dxActivity.this);
            }
        }

    }, 3000);
```

Game is started and then it crashing:

> Interface method not part of interface class
> Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.isConnected, referenced from method com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.getRequests
>
> unable to resolve interface method 12116: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;.isConnected ()Z

Cannot understand where can be trouble, why this methods is not visible...

Answer (score 0):

Found out that during previous google play services update something gonna wrong, deleted and reinstalled then found out that current version is 4323000, modified manifest file to pick this version and everything looks works now.